Swagger show decimal as 0.00 instead of 0
I have this class:
public class CostDto
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
}

In the swagger it shows this:
{
    "Id": 0,
    "Price": 0
}

And I would prefer this:
{
    "Id": 0,
    "Price": 0.00
}

This would more clearly indicate to the user that the returned value of Price is of type decimal, not integer. It this possible at all in swagger?
I found some posts referring to something like this, but it doesn't seem to work:
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.MapType<decimal>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal" });
    options.MapType<decimal?>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal", Nullable = true });
});


You could try this:
public class DecimalSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema.Type == "number" && schema.Format == "decimal")
        {
            schema.Example = OpenApiAnyFactory.CreateFromJson("0.01");
        }
    }
}

services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SchemaFilter<DecimalSchemaFilter>();

    options.MapType<decimal>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal" });
    options.MapType<decimal?>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal", Nullable = true });
});


Thanks! It worked, except that I had to use "schema.Example = OpenApiAnyFactory.CreateFromJson("0.01");" because the "CreateFor" has been deprecated and 0.00 is always shortened to 0. Maybe you can add this in your answer? I use Swashbuckle 6.6.1.

Great, I will add it.

Swagger UI drops the zero decimal portion of floating-point numbers in displayed examples, it's known behavior: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7337
As a workaround, you can specify a custom example value with a non-zero decimal part:
public class CostDto
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    /// <example>12.34</example>
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
}

